# Cannot index into a null array

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I am running a simple code in PowerShell but i get the error Cannot index into a null array. I am new in PowerShell, but basically i am traying to delete but first view all records from a big list with specific date. Please Help

```
 $web= Get-SPWeb "http://intranet****"

 $listname= "Guideline"

 $list= $web.Lists[$listname]

 $items= $list.Items | where {$_["Created"] -eq '2/9/2018'}

 foreach($item in $items)
{

 Write-Host created : $Item["created"]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your scripts as shown below and try again:

1. Use **-gt** and **-lt** for datetime column instead of **-eq**
2. Change $Item["created"] to $item["Created"], capital "C"

```
$listname= "Guideline"

 $list= $web.Lists[$listname]

 $items= $list.Items | where {$_["Created"] -gt '2/9/2018' -and $_["Created"] -lt '3/9/2018'}

 $items.Count

 foreach($item in $items)
{

 Write-Host created : $item["Created"]

}
```